# time value in seconds to time format 0m0.000s convertion

Tags: shell, time

i have the time value return by date + %s. i need to change that time in seconds to the format 0m0.000s
how to convert a time in seconds to time format "0M0.000s"

please tell me the calculation

or please tell me how can i make it possible in shell script

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo 123.456 | awk '{printf "%sm%ss\n", int($1/60), $1 % 60}'
2m3.456s
```